# Scope of rvalue when immediately passing its member

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, lifetime, temporary

When does an rvalue get invalidated/is considered undefined?

Below are two examples, one of which the rvalue is stored in a local variable and then actions on that local variable are performed, the other example shows a member of the rvalue being passed immediately to a function which also operates on the data.

I suspect example 1 is undefined behaviour, as in my own code (this is a minimal reproducible example), the application completely fails, meanwhile 2 does not. Is 2 also undefined behaviour? Which of the examples are?

```
struct container {
    int data[5];
    container(int a) {
        data[0] = a;
    }
};

void main() {
    int* arr = container(123).data;

    // ... do stuff with data
}
```

vs

```
struct container {
    int data[5];
    container(int a) {
        data[0] = a;
    }
};

void do_stuff_with_data(int* data) {
    // ... do stuff with data
}
void main() {
    do_stuff_with_data(container(123).data);
}
```

Comment: My name has been stolen! :-) Cheers fellow superb beeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd one is well-formed. [Temporaries](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) will be destroyed after the full expression.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
>   created, ...

Given `do_stuff_with_data(container(123).data);`, the temporary object (i.e. `container(123)`) will be destroyed after the full expression, which contains the invocation of `do_stuff_with_data`.

On the other hand the 1st one might have undefined behavior. After the full expression the temporary object has been destroyed and `arr` becomes dangled. Any dereference on it later leads to UB.